# How can i efficiently implement centered bottom navbar design in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to implement this bottom navigation bar design using flutter for mobile, and I can't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong. I want it to be evenly spaced and centered. This is the design image[image]

I tried different approaches but this is the closest output to the design I could get [image]

For more context, this is the code I used

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:iconly/iconly.dart';

class DashBoardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashBoardScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashBoardScreenState createState() => _DashBoardScreenState();
}

class _DashBoardScreenState extends 
State<DashBoardScreen> {
  var currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    height: size.width * .155,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 4,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * .024),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          setState(
            () {
              currentIndex = index;
            },
          );
        },
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
              curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: index == currentIndex ? 0 : size.width * .029,
                right: size.width * .0422,
                left: size.width * .0422,
              ),
              width: size.width * .128,
              height: index == currentIndex ? 4 : 0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xff25307e),
              ),
            ),
            Icon(
              index == currentIndex
                  ? listOfIconsBold[index]
                  : listOfIconsLight[index],
              size: size.width * .076,
              color: index == currentIndex
                  ? Color(0xff25307e)
                  : Colors.black38,
            ),
            Text(
              listOfText[index],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: index == currentIndex
                    ? Color(0xff25307e)
                    : Colors.black38,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
  }

  List<IconData> listOfIconsLight = [
IconlyLight.category,
IconlyLight.chart,
IconlyLight.document,
IconlyLight.work
  ];
   List<IconData> listOfIconsBold = [
     IconlyBold.category,
     IconlyBold.chart,

     IconlyBold.document,
     IconlyBold.work
   
];

      List<String> listOfText = ['Dashboard', 'Analytics', 'My Products', 'Manage'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `ListView` widget unless you want it to be scrollable.

Just make a `Row` with `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` to let it take up the whole width and `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` to center/space the children. The `children:` don't have to be a predefined list. It can also be a function that returns a list of widgets (your icons and texts in the column)

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: navItems(),
)

...

List<Widget> navItems() {
  List<Widget> w = [];
  
  for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    w.add(Column(/*same column as in your code*/));
  }
  
  return w;
}
```